# Incorporating a method into a tic tac toe board

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TicTacToeGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe (you are X)!");
        String gameBox = new TicTacToe().toString();
        System.out.println(gameBox);
        userMove(gameBox);
    }


    public static void userMove(String gameBoard) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        int row, column;
        String [][] moveX = new String [3][3];
        do {
            System.out.print("Move location: ");
            row = keyboard.nextInt();
            column = keyboard.nextInt();
        } while (row < 0 || row > 2 || column < 0 || column > 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < moveX.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < moveX[i].length; j++){
                if (row == i && column == j){
                    moveX[i][j] = "X";
                }
                else 
                    moveX[i][j] = " ";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(moveX));

    }
```

I have the user enter which location they want to put their X on the game board. The game board, gameBox (taken from another class), looks like this:

```
=============
|   |   |   |
=============
|   |   |   |
=============
|   |   |   |
=============
```

How can I get the "X" inside the the game board?

Comment: Since the `TicTacToe` object is responsible for creating the game board, it will need to know the row/column X/O values so that it can print them.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to this, how might I go about doing that?

Comment: You'll need to modify the `TicTacToe` class.  You could create a new method that takes the 3x3 array as a parameter and returns the new game board as a string.  Or, you could store the 3x3 array as a member variable in `TicTacToe`, then create a method that records an individual move.